Is an interaction term essentially interpreted as just another independent variable?
I'm trying to understand if the linear regression model interprets an interaction term as just another independent variable?
This is the formula for linear regression with 2 independent variables without an interaction term(let's assume x1 is continous and x2 is Binary Categorical):
b0 + b1x1 + b2x2
And this is for with an interaction term.
b0 + b1x1 + b2x2 + b3x1x2
Would the regression model just interpret x1x2 as a third independent variable i.e. x3 so it would just see it as b3x3 (which we know consists of the interaction effect of x2 on x1 or vice versa)
Thank you very much.

I'm not sure what you mean by "interprets" in this context. The model (or the program that runs it) does calculations.  It's we humans who interpret. Are you asking about the math behind the equation?

@PeterFlom In that case, can we humans interpret it as a third independent variable?

Not really.  It's an interaction. It will make the interpretation of main effects much trickier.

@PeterFlom While I understand it's an interaction. The maths and calculations behind it treat and represent it as if it's a 3rd independent variable. It has its own coefficient, standard error, etc... That's why I was asking if it can be interpreted as just a pseudo third independent variable (bo +b1x1 +b2x2 + b3x3) where x3 just represents (x1x2 i.e. the interaction). Thanks again.

I guess it depends on exactly what you mean by "interpret"

Can I suggest you ask in terms of what specifically you will do with the results. “Interpret” is leading down a rabbit hole.

@rolando2 Thank you for taking the time to explain. I'm trying to develop the intuition behind how the parameters of the interaction term are calculated (coefficient,standard error, etc...). From the way I "interpreted" it is that the program just considers it as another independent variable (even though we know that it is actually the interaction of 2 independent variables).

@Mandem: For the program, it is just another independent variable, yes. The calculations are done in exactly the same way. At the level of the matrix algebra, there is no difference. Humans trying to interpret the results impose more structure.
